# Copy content from one file to another in C

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

Given one txt file Im trying to make a C program that copy the content of that into other which name is passed by arguments.The program must read blocks of 512 bytes from the source file and write the bytes read in the destination file.

My attempt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("ERROR: Missing arguments\n");
        exit(1);    
    }

    int fdo, fdd;

    if((fdo = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        printf("ERROR: Origin file %s can not be opened\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1){
        printf("ERROR: Dest. file %s can not be opened\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    } 

    char buff[512];
    size_t n_bytes;

    while((n_bytes = read(fdo,buff,512)) > 0){
        if(write(fdd,buff,n_bytes) < 0){
            printf("Can not write buffer content in %s \n", argv[2]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if(n_bytes < 0){
        printf("Can not read %s file \n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fdo);
    close(fdd);

    return 0;
}
```

The content of the file test.txt is:

```
abcdef
1890
```

And their permissions are:

```
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxrwxr-x 1 usuarioso usuarioso 17048 nov 23 16:15 copyrf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usuarioso usuarioso   774 nov 23 16:39 copyrf.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usuarioso usuarioso    12 nov 23 16:52 test.txt
```

However when I execute it I get the following:

```
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$ gcc -o copyrf copyrf.c
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$ ./copyrf test.txt test1.txt
abcdef
1890
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$ ls -l
total 28
-rwxrwxr-x 1 usuarioso usuarioso 17008 nov 23 17:00 copyrf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usuarioso usuarioso   771 nov 23 16:59 copyrf.c
-rw-rw-rw- 1 usuarioso usuarioso     0 nov 23 17:00 test1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usuarioso usuarioso    12 nov 23 16:52 test.txt
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$ cat test1.txt
usuarioso@usuarioso-virtualbox:~/Documentos/SO 2022/pr2/API de ficheros y directorios$
```

i.e the file test1.txt is created but is empty and the content of the file test.txt is printed in console.

What am I missing?

Comment: And now you know why  whoever taught you to cram `if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC) == -1)` all into one line taught you **a very bad and very bug-prone way to write C code**.  If you had written `fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC); if (fdd == -1)...` in **two lines** of code instead of cramming it all into one you never would have wasted all the time you did on this bug.

Comment: Not only that, you could have written `int fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC); if (fdd == -1)...` in the **exact same two lines of code** it took to define and then assign to `fdd` in the `if` statement anyway.  So the cramming of everything into the `if` statement saves you nothing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang's gcc points out the problem pretty well:

```
$ gcc temp.c
temp.c:19:12: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1){
       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
temp.c:19:12: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1){
           ^
       (                                                 )
temp.c:19:12: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1){
       ^
           ==
```

... in particular, `fdd` is being set to the result of `(open(...) == -1)`, i.e. to `1` if the `open()` call returned `-1`, or to `0` if the `open()` call returned any other value.  Since neither `0` nor `1` is the value of the file-descriptor returned by `open()`, your subsequent calls to `write(fdd, ...)` are using an invalid file-descriptor value and therefore failing.

The fix would be to add parentheses as you did for your first/open-for-read `open()` call, making it like this instead:

```
if((fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)) == -1){
```

In addition to that, you need to add `O_WRONLY` to the `oflag` argument of your second call to `open()`, otherwise `fdd` will not be allowed to write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot some parentheses so `fdd` is getting set to 0 or 1 instead of the return value of `open`.  Compare it to the `fdo` code. It's best to avoid assignment inside an expression like that unless you really know what you're doing.  It would also be one of the first things to remove while simplifying your code to make a minimal complete verifiable example for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```c
if((fdo = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
```

you put the assignment into brackets. This first assigns the opened file descriptor to `fdo` and then checks if that value is equal to -1 afterwards.

On the other hand, in second case:

```c
if(fdd = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1)
```

you did not put the assignment in the brackets. Because of this, the `==` operator is evaluated first, which returns a value of 0 (false) or 1 (true) instead of a valid file descriptor. This value is then assigned to `fdd`, causing you to write to a wrong file descriptor (standard output).